# Residue at $\infty$ of $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1)}$ is $0$ but the residues of the only finite pole at $0$ is $-\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, residue-calculus, infinity

I need to find the residue at $\infty$ of $$f(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1)}$$
I wrote the function as $$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z} \hspace{1cm} \text{given}\hspace{5mm} g(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z(z-1)} \quad \text{which is analytic at z=0}$$

Since $z=0$ is a simple pole for $f(z)$ I evaluated the limit as $z\rightarrow0$ which gives $-\pi$.

Now to evaluate the reside at $\infty$ I used the substitution $z=\frac{1}{w}$ and evaluated the $\text{Res} \{ \frac{1}{w^2} f(\frac{1}{w}); w=0\}$, but $$\frac{1}{w^2}f(\frac{1}{w})=w\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{w}\right)}{1-w}$$

It has residue equals $0$ at $w=0$.
The residue at $\infty$ should be equals to the sums of all the residues of the finite poles  changed by a minus, in our case should be $\pi$.

I don't know if I'm using the definition wrong or if there's a mistake in the procedure, please help me find the error.

Comment: I think the minus sign you're missing, you used it already to make an integral in the positive orientarion because $z=1/w$ changes orientation.

Comment: Otherwise, you're looking for the residue of $-1/w^2 f(1/w)$

Comment: The limit, $\lim_{z\to\infty}\sin(\pi z)/(z^2(z-1))$, does not exist.  The sine function has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: @FrancescoGreco Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1)}$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=\infty\right)&=\text{Res}\left(-\frac1{z^2}f(1/z), z=0\right)\\\\
&=\text{Res}\left(\frac{z\sin(\pi/z)}{z-1}, z=0\right)
\end{align}$$

Note that $\sin(\pi/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ and thus $\hat f(z) =\frac{z\sin(\pi/z)}{z-1}$ also has an essential singularity at $z=0$.  In fact, its value as $z\to 0$ takes on all possible values and therefore its limit fails to converge.  Moreover, its residue is ***not*** equal to zero (A function with an essential singularity can have zero residue.).

To compute the reside of $\hat f(z)=\frac{z\sin(\pi/z)}{z-1}$ at $z=0$, we expand $\hat f(z)$ in a Laurent series.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
\hat f(z)&=\left(1-\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(\pi/z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(\pi/z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}-\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(\pi/z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(\pi/z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}-\sum_{p=0}^\infty \sum_{q=0}^p \frac{(-1)^q(\pi)^{2q+1}}{(2p+1)!}z^{p-3q-1}\tag1
\end{align}$$

The reside of the first series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is easily seen to be equal to $\pi$.  For the second term, note that only those terms for which $p=3q$ are implicated.  But in that case, the result is $\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^q(\pi)^{2q+1}}{(2q+1)!}=\sin(\pi)=0$.

Hence, we find that

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^2(z-1)}, z=\infty\right)=\pi$$

as was expected!

Comment: The residue at an essential singularity at $0$ *can* be zero: consider $\sum_{n\ge2}z^{-n}$. It isn't in this particular case.

Comment: @egreg Hi Greg.  Yes.  That is correct.  Let me edit to make things clearer.  See if the edited version makes better sense please.

Comment: “Now we show that the residue at $0$ is not zero”. In the current form, it still seems that the residue is nonzero just because there's an essential singularity.

Comment: "Moreover, its residue is not equal to zero."  I don't see the leap to incorrectly conclude that essential singularities have non-zero residues.  But I'll edit once more.

Comment: @FrancescoGreco Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.